# Attaching a keyup handler using jQuery does not work for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the written integer value for different operations but it does not work. But a similar thing on another page is working properly. How can I fix it?

HTML code:

```
        <div class="row modal-body">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label for="contengencyrate">रकम</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <input type="number" step="any" name="amount" min="0" max="{{buktani_baki}}"  id="amount" value="">

                <!-- <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" min="0" max="{{total.amount__sum}}" step="any" value=""> -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>


$('#amount').keyup(function () {

        var val = $('#amount').val();
        // var total = $("#total").val()
        console.log(val,890898908080);
        console.log(123456);
        // $('#percent').val(rakamTopercent(val, total))
    })


</script>
```

How can I solve this? no error in the console. sometimes it shows error like:

> "additional-methods.min.js?_=1609744418426:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined"

Comment: please give me some suggestion what can i do, is this is due to given cdn

Comment: why are you console logging `val` before defining it? Your error must be in `additional-methods.js file`. Because this looks clean!

Comment: use $(document).ready({ Here Your jQuery code })

Comment: stillKonfuzed  this by mistake when i copy code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script is not loading or some issue in CDN. Use Java Script for a similar results. Eg.
HTML:

```
<div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>

<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput' id='chatinput'>
```

CSS:{if required}

```
.printchatbox 
    {border-width:thick 10px;border-style: solid; 
    background-color:#fff;
    line-height: 2;color:#6E6A6B;font-size: 14pt;text-align:left;float: middle;
    border: 3px solid #969293;width:40%;
     height:2em;   
}
```

Java Script Code:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');

inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
```

i think this works

Answer (score 0):

You are loading 2 different versions of `jquery`:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Use only 1 version of jquery, version 1.11 is probably too old

---

If your script runs before the input element is rendered - for example if the script is defined in the `head` element it won't find the `input` by id

You can wait for the full document to be `ready` before querying and attaching a listener

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Wait for the full document to be parsed and loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // And then try to find and atach a listener
      $("#amount").keyup(function() {
        var val = $("#amount").val();
        // var total = $("#total").val()
        console.log(val, 890898908080);
        console.log(123456);
        // $('#percent').val(rakamTopercent(val, total))
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row modal-body">
    <div class="col-4">
      <label for="contengencyrate">रकम</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7">
      <input type="number" step="any" name="amount" min="0" max="{{buktani_baki}}" id="amount" value="" />

      <!-- <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" min="0" max="{{total.amount__sum}}" step="any" value=""> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it works properly here, but when i even copy same code also it does not work for me. what is the problem here.

Comment: Then something else in your code is causing a side effect, I noticed you are loading jQuery twice and added an update to my answer